# Query optimization: max() in subquery

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, query-optimization

```
select active from websites where id = (select max(id) from websites where url = 'google.com')

id  select_type table     type   possible_keys  key      key_len  ref    rows  Extra
1   PRIMARY     websites  const  PRIMARY        PRIMARY  4        const  1   
2   SUBQUERY    websites  ref    url            url      767             1867  Using where
```

How can I optimize this query? The `url` field is index and `id` is the primary key. So why is it going through all the rows?

Comment: Are you looking for only the last ACTIVE RECORD ID for the given URL???  Or, just "give me the active status of whatever the last ID is for the given URL"... they are two separate queries...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MAX always process all rows - use order by and limit - so query will look this way

```
 SELECT * FROM wbsites WHERE url = '...' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

For this case subquery is not required

EDIT: Forgot where url

Comment: Good idea, but here's what I get now: `1 SIMPLE websites   ref url url 767 const 2334 Using where; Using filesort`

Comment: and what index type is PRIMARY ? Binary tree or hash ?

Comment: and what will happen if you put .. FROM websites USE INDEX(PRIMARY) ..( or USE INDEX(id) - i don't remember correct syntax now )

Comment: another idea is to create combined index ( url, id ) - it could help

Answer (score 0):

Consider

```
alter table websites add index a (url, active);
select active 
    from websites 
    where url = 'google.com' 
    order by id desc 
    limit 1;
```

Comment: The query is good, though additional index with `active` is not needed, this column is used only in select.

Comment: shouldn't active column in the index will promote the query to "uses index", though?

Comment: Index on url alone would be enough for that, at least if where condition is selective enough. But if most rows have 'google.com' then it would be better to use just PRIMARY index to find rows in descending id order and check their url.