# MySQL MAX subquery

Tags: php, mysql, max

I have a problem with MySQL at this moment.
I'm trying to determine the highest **float** value from my table like this:

```
SELECT `id` 
FROM `LOTRESULTS` 
WHERE 
  `value`= (SELECT MAX(value) FROM `LOTRESULTS`) AND 
  `lot_id` = 180 
ORDER BY `id` DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

This works whenever I choose let's say id 180, but none of the other combinations work.

There are 3 entries with 180 as lot_id, and 2 occurences with 179 as lot_id, etc.
It just works randomly, it fails on most of the entries in the DB.

Am I doing something wrong? Should I change the datatype of the value column?

Thanks in advance guys!

p.s. I've also tried:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `LOTRESULTS` WHERE `value`= (SELECT MAX(value) FROM
`LOTRESULTS`) AND `lot_id` = 180
```

and

```
SELECT `id` FROM `LOTRESULTS` WHERE `value`= (SELECT MAX(value) AS
`value` FROM `LOTRESULTS`) AND `lot_id` = 180
```

with the same results...

Comment: "It just works randomly, it fails on most of the entries in the DB." Fails in what way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Query optimization: max() in subquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347096/query-optimization-max-in-subquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really have to use sub-query, or JOIN,
a simple where + order + limit will do :-

```
SELECT id FROM LOTRESULTS WHERE lot_id = 180 ORDER BY value DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

Your inner query is going to fetch the highest `value` field ANYWHERE in the table, regardless of which lot it's part of. The outer query then tries to retrieve all the ids that have that max value AND are part of a specific lot.

If the max value belongs to lot `123`, but you're fetching the ids for lot `456`, you'll get no results.

The query should be:

```
SELECT id
FROM LOTRESULTS
WHERE value = (
    SELECT MAX(value) AS value
    FROM LOTRESULTS
    WHERE lot_id = 180
) AND lot_id = 180
```

The doubled `lot_id = 180` handles the case where two+ different lots may share the same maximum value. Without the 'outer and', you'd get the ids for the two+ lots.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM LOTRESULTS
WHERE whatever...
ORDER BY value DESC
LIMIT 1
```